# what files to share android app sourcecode

Tags: android, share

What is the best way to share android app with friend like i send him the whole project files or should i delete some files like cache or **gen** folder or something.

i just started in android development and i want the right way to share app without having problems on the other side.

also i sow some files in the project like **android private library** and **bin** folder should i share them to or is there files i need to delete before that ?

Comment: Export an `.apk` file. That is one single file with everything you need. You can install your app directly from that file.

Comment: @Takendarkk i know that BUT i want to share the **sourcecode** NOT apk file, Thanks

Comment: In your filesystem go to your workspace and then just copy the whole folder that has your project name.

Comment: @Takendarkk Yes but i was asking is there any files i need to delete before that ? because i see some projects on **github** it looks like it has some missing folders and it works fine, so i need to know is there anything i need to delete before that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To share the app just for running - share the `apk` file.

To share the app for development purposes ( sharing the source code ), share the folders

`src`

`res`

`lib` ( If you've added some external dependencies )

`assets` ( If you've added something extra there )

And following files

`AndroidManifest.xml`

`project.properties`

You can safely ignore following

`bin`

`gen`

and others, as these are automatically generated.

Answer (score 1):

You can delete the gen and bin directorys, when we complie or build the project, files in the two directory will recreate.

Answer (score 0):

You can upload `code` you wanted to share in `www.github.com`, it also provides `private` mode, where you can choose members who have access to your repository

If your don't want to share the `code`, then you can share only `.apk` file of `bin` folder